# jQuery javascript keyfilter - how to validate "page 1 of 3"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, wicket

we are using wicket and jquery keyfilter plugin in our project.

i am wondering what is the best solution to validate 2 fields for "page x of y" that checks that y is greater than x

we are currently using the keyfilter plugin to check the numbers are non-zero, mandatory and numeric

```
inputField.add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>(
"mask-pintnonzero", " "));
inputField.add(new AttributeAppender("onblur", new Model<String>("$('#order').checkMandatoryField(this.value,this);"), " "));
```

the closest i can get it to work is this:

```
totalPageField.add(new AttributeAppender("onblur", true,
  new Model<String("$('#field').checkValueIsWithinRange($('#order').val(),this,1,this.value);")," "));
```

the only problem seem to be in keyfilter.js with the comparison. if i enter 6 and 10, it thinks its invalid. if i enter 6 and 8 its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, it doesn't seem like you can use both KeyFilter and get the functionality you are hoping for.  Six will always be greater than One and you need to go through that step in order to type 6 and 10.

Personally, I wouldn't use KeyFilter for something this complicated - it is designed for things like telephone numbers, zip codes, etc.  You need to perform this validation onBlur (as you mentioned worked) or on form submit.